# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in 'app/home/home.module

Tags: angular, cli

Al ejecutar cualquiera de estos dos comandos

- ```
  ng build --prod`
  ```
- ```
  ng serve --prod`
  ```

Me genera el siguiente error:

> ```
> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in 'app/home/home.module'
> Error: Cannot find 'default' in 'app/home/home.module'.
> ```

Código de *HomeModule*:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HeaderModule,
    routes
  ],
  declarations: [ModelComponent, HomeComponent, CardComponent, DurationPipe],
  providers: [VideoService]
})
export default class HomeModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Hola User, bienvenido. Qué es ese codigo?  Puedes explicar qué intentas o qué sucede?

Comment: Intento hacer ng build --prod para generar la carpeta dist, me crea la carpeta, pero al arrancar la aplicación me genera el error de que no puede encontrar 'default' en el home.module.

Comment: Has de explicarlo en la pregunta, todo lo bien que puedas. Edita la pregunta.

Comment: Ng serve --prod también genera mismo error, pero solo con ng serve me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta en inglés , quizás te ayude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917105/rc-5-throws-cannot-find-default-when-lazy-loading-module-with-routes

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe estar en el **home.routing** ve que estés importando bien los componentes o no estés haciendo algo indebido como el uso de:

```
<default></default>
```

¿Podrías comentar por favor qué tienes en el routing?